# Signing IIS Response

Tags: iis, soap, hmac, signing

I am trying to create a SOAP service where I want every response to be signed using either a HMAC SHA 256 or an RSA Private key.

My original plan was to intercept the response using an HttpModule. I would then read the body and calculate a HMAC SHA 256 hash and add that to a custom response header. That way it would be possible to verify the content of the body using that header hash.

But the only way I can find to actually read the body is through a Filter. When I do that, I can't write new response headers because headers have already been sent.

Am I going about this completely backwards?

Comment: It would be rather an interesting question as SOAP protocol itself has defined secure approaches. Why do you want to implement your own?

Comment: Good point... I will look into doing it like that. Thanks.